# Node.js get modified XML into variable for writing

Tags: xml, node.js

I have been searching all over and I have come up with some good answers, but this last small detail of my task, I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a Node.js implementation that contains the following function. The point of this function is to change some of the settings of an xml file on the server. So far I think I have pretty much everything done, but I can't figure out how to get the processed xml string to write back to the file.

`$data` is the JSON object from the POST.

```
function SaveSettings() {
    fs.readFile('config.xml', function (err, data) { //Read the XML file to a string
        if(err) {throw err;}    //If and error, throw error
        var $xml = $(data.toString()).find('settings').each(function () { //Process XML
            $(this).find('background > color').text($data.backgroundColor);
            $(this).find('background > image').text($data.backgroundImage);
            if($data.startupEnabled === "on") {
                $(this).find('startup > enabled').text("true");
            } else {
                $(this).find('startup > enabled').text("false");
            }
            if($data.splashEnabled === "on") {
                $(this).find('startup > splash > enabled').text("true");
            } else {
                $(this).find('startup > splash > enabled').text("false");
            }
            $(this).find('startup > splash > image').text($data.splashImage);
            $(this).find('security > password').text($data.password);
       });

       console.log($xml.toString()); //Contains the output of the jQuery object (Not XML)

        fs.writeFile('config.xml', data.toString(), function (err) {
            if(err) {throw err;}
        }); //data.toString() contains the original XML, unmodified.
    });

    ...
}
```

I know that this could be done with other languages, but I would really like a Node.js solution. Also I do have the `jstoxml` module and `jquery` module loaded in the implementation.

Comment: what part isn't actually working? You have an `fs.writeFile` command there, is it not getting called? Is it getting called but it's not writing? Help us help you =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah I thought I might have to be a little more clear about it, sorry about that. My problem is I don't know how to get the modified XML string from the jquery function. The `fs.writeFile` is working fine and is getting called, but the `data.toString()` still contains the original xml string, not the modified on. If I could just get the modified one, I could throw it in the `fs.writeFile` and I'd be done...

Comment: then you may want to change your post to ask how you can get the modified XML into a variable for writing, instead. I'd assume that putting your modified data into a throw-away `div` and then getting `div.innerHTML` would work just fine. Although looking at your code, what's $data? where is that even created? (If you're in Nodejs, you probably want to use a gruntfile with a js-hint task to catch rogue vars)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated my question per your recommendations, thank you, and I added what `$data` is. It is basically the JSON containing the POST data with the values from the form the user is submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to pass that `$data` into the functions, not rely on it being global. That said, you can probably get the XML code by doing:

```
var div = $("<div></div>");
div.append($(this));
var newXMLcode = div.html();
```

Also note that you're using `$(this)` all over the place - you probably want to cache that instead, like `var $this = $(this)` and then using `$this` instead for all your jQuery-wrapped requirements.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I took your advice and cached the `$(this)`. Then I did all my selections from the root level and wrote everything back to the file. Works great now! I have been working on getting this to work for a day and a half. Finally I can move on to other development. I knew it had to be simple, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to pull the data... Thanks again.